# Updating changes after Hot reload in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am rewriting my code because I have to see some changes But when I change my code and "hot reload" it does not get reflected in emulator.

Everytime I need to full restart the app

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Dialog leadDialog = Dialog(
  child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Text(
              'Leaderboard',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 22.0),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(color: Colors.redAccent),
          Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30.0,
                  backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/cat.jpg')),
            ),
            Text('Neha'),
            RaisedButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 15.0),
              textColor: Colors.black,
              child: Text(
                '546',
                style: TextStyle(),
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
            ),
          ])
        ],
      )),
);
```

Expected: On hot reload I should be able to see the changes.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload#recent-ui-change-is-excluded, please refer to this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your widget in a variable outside the WidgetLifeCycle it would probably wouldn't render every state change.
Maybe make your widget a builder method that will render every single time its parent renders.

Also read about [FlutterByExample - Widget Lifecycle](https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/), [Flutter Docs Widget Intro](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro)

```
WidgetBuilder leadDialog = (BuildContext context) => Dialog();
```

Comment: onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => leadDialog);
              },

Comment: Above is the code which I wrote to call the Dialog widget and I am getting this error :

 lib/pages/main.dart:166:62: Error: A value of type 'Widget Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.

Comment: Where is the "leadDialog" being used? try putting it **inside** the render() method of the widget. What I provided above is a WidgetBuilder you must also use it inside the render using "leadDialog()".

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. The following steps worked for me

- Stop app
- Uninstall it from device/emulator
- run `flutter clean`
- re run the app